# How to add two values to an object list with a For Loop in C#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, object, instantiation

Wording this question is kind of hard, but I am creating a deck of cards with a for loop that stops after looping 52 times. Inside of this 'for loop', I need to instantiate an object called Card from my Card class and add the values to the Card class. However, my constructor in the Card class takes in 2 values. I can't remember how to add two values of "i" to an object in one loop without repeating.. In case that doesn't make sense I added my code below.

This is my static method with the for loop:

```
public static List<Card> CreateDeck()
    {
        // This class should create a deck of cards
        // This should use one or more loops to create
        // each card in a standard, 4-suit deck of cards
        // As you create the cards add them to a List of cards
        List<Card> createDeck = new List<Card>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            //Need to instantiate the card class and add 2 values at
            //the same time
            //ex: Card deck = new Card(int suit, int value)
        }


        // Assume a suit of 0 is Spades, 1 is Hearts, 2 is Diammonds, and 3 is Clubs
        // If the card value is 12 and suit is 0 the card is essentially
        // the Queen of Spades. If the value is 1 and the suit is 3 it is
        // the Ace of Clubs.

        // This method should return the list when complete.
        return createDeck;
```

And this is the object class that I am instantiating (I'm not quite done with this class yet. I still need to add values but I have to create the deck of cards first):

```
public class Card
{
    // Create a private field for the card's suit (This should be an integer)
    // It will eventually store a number from 0 to 3
    private int _suit;


    // Create a public property for the value of the card. This will hold a
    // number from 1 to 13
    public int CardValue { get; }

    // Create a constructor that accepts suit and value in parameters and
    // sets the value and suit classmember variables accordingly
    public Card(int suit, int cardValue)
    {
        _suit = suit;
        CardValue = cardValue;
    }
```

Can someone help me out?

I edited my code and now I have the code below but when I run it through a foreach loop, it doesn't print out correctly.. I am missing something. I just don't know what.

```
List<Card> createDeck = new List<Card>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < 13; v++)
            {
                Card deck = new Card(v, i);
                createDeck.Add(deck);
            }

        }

        // Assume a suit of 0 is Spades, 1 is Hearts, 2 is Diammonds, and 3 is Clubs
        // If the card value is 12 and suit is 0 the card is essentially
        // the Queen of Spades. If the value is 1 and the suit is 3 it is
        // the Ace of Clubs.
        foreach (Card card in createDeck)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card);
        }
```

It prints out War.Card

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're not a totally new user to the website, but I recommend that you do research before posting questions so that they're not marked as Closed or downvoted. For example, C# for-loops are well-documented and have numerous examples all over the web. A simple Google search led me to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.asp) page, which answers your question about incrementing the index of the for-loop.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968651/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-score-value-for-cards-in-a-deck and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383468/creating-a-deck-of-cards-in-c-sharp for additional useful insights into better ways to implement card decks in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Card> CreateDeck()
{
    // This class should create a deck of cards
    // This should use one or more loops to create
    // each card in a standard, 4-suit deck of cards
    // As you create the cards add them to a List of cards
    List<Card> createDeck = new List<Card>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        int suit = i % 4;
        int value = i / 4;
        createDeck.Add(new Card(int suit, int value));
    }


    // Assume a suit of 0 is Spades, 1 is Hearts, 2 is Diammonds, and 3 is Clubs
    // If the card value is 12 and suit is 0 the card is essentially
    // the Queen of Spades. If the value is 1 and the suit is 3 it is
    // the Ace of Clubs.

    // This method should return the list when complete.
    return createDeck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 0; i < 52; i+=2)` 
Note: i+=2

Comment: And then in the instantiation put Card deck = new Card( i , i )